# STAR vs Bowtie2

Tags: sequence-alignment, bowtie2, star

What is the fundamental difference between STAR and Bowtie(2). Specifically, what is the difference in their final output (regardless of run-time differences, speed, memory usage etc.). Both seem to work on the same kind of input *.fastq files without discriminating what they are associated with and generate an output version of the *.fastq files. Would my downstream analysis be incorrect if I use Bowtie2 where STAR was supposed to be used, and vice versa? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the fundamental difference between STAR and Bowtie(2).

STAR for mapping spliced (i.e. with introns) short RNA-seq reads against a genome. Bowtie2 for mapping short reads without splicing.

> Would my downstream analysis be incorrect if I use Bowtie2 where STAR was supposed to be used (?)

Yes. If you use bowtie2 to map spliced short reads against a genome, STAR-based downstream analysis is likely to be wrong.

> ... and vice versa?

If you map genomic reads with STAR, the result will be suboptimal. Use the right tool for the right task.

Answer (score 3):

The seeds are clustered together by proximity to a selected set of ‘anchor’ seeds in the 2nd phase of the STAR algorithm,  but this •clustering/stitching/scoring process• is not present in Bowtie2.

[image]

[mapping by performing a two-step process](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l8dAS9fA3wpPiExRXGIJ4aE4gJltl_1A/view?usp=sharing)